# How can I add a currency switcher to my language container at the top of rwd theme

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme

I am using my own custom version of the RWD theme and would like to know how I can display a currency switcher in the div `.header-language-background`, how would i go about doing this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create `local.xml` at `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/layout` if it not exist, then call currency dropdown by below code:

```
<default>
<reference name="store_language">
           <block type="directory/currency" name="topcurrency"  template="directory/currency.phtml"/>
 </reference>
<default>
```

then call this block using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topcurrency') ?>` in `languages.phtml` which located at `app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/switch/`

Comment: I don't want it in my header , I want it in the language switcher area at the top of the site and would preferably like to insert it with html in header.phtml so i can make sure it is in the right div

Comment: where do you put the php code? to call it

Comment: i had already told you that you need to call `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topcurrency') ?>` at languages.phtml

Comment: This is incorrect, there is '<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('currency_switcher') ?>' in my header.phtml